# Getting TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL Error in server log for angular-ionic web application

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, server

I have my application deployed in a server and I am getting below error continuously in logs.
I checked in code and no where we are passing wrong url to any function.

10|main | TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL 10|main | at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5) 10|main | at onParseError (node:internal/url:552:9) 10|main | at new URL (node:internal/url:628:5) 10|main | at engine_CommonEngine. (app/server/main.js:1:6222354) 10|main | at Generator.next () 10|main | at app/server/main.js:1:6565549 10|main | at new ZoneAwarePromise (app/serve r/main.js:1:3593191) 10|main | at __awaiter (app/server/main.js:1 :6565190) 10|main | at engine_CommonEngine.render (app /server/main.js:1:6222245) 10|main | at View.engine (app/server/main.js

After verifying at code level I am not passing any wrong url.
My angular version is 11.2.14

How to get rid of that error? Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.